# Как сделать выборку из таблицы 1 основываясь на значении поля из таблицы 2?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня в таблице **user_words** есть метка id_word (id записи в таблице *translates*), id_user и date_add.

А в таблице **translates** есть информация о языке (**target**).

Мне нужно вывести все записи id_user = 1 за сегодняшнюю дату, у которых в таблице *translates* столбец target = 'test'

Я пытался делать так:

```
SELECT `id_word`
FROM `user_words` as g WHERE g.id_user = 1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(g.date_add, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
LEFT JOIN `translates` as u ON u.id = g.id_word AND u.target = 'test'
```

Но это выдает ошибку.

Что я делаю не так? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 сделал `SELECT g.id_word, g.id_user` но все равно не работает

Comment: SELECT `id_word`
FROM `user_words` as g 
LEFT JOIN `translates` as u ON u.id = g.id_word WHERE g.id_user = 1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(g.date_add, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() AND u.target = 'test'